# Does google analytics only track known browsers?

Tags: google-analytics

I have a desktop application that uses CEF for displaying a built in web page.

I have customized the User-Agent (`Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) DesktopApp MyAppName/1.0 (MyApp release 1.0 stamp 99999) Safari/537.36`) but Google Analytics only shows as Safari 537.36.

Are browsers outside the known universe of real browsers supported by GA when looking up browsers used? I would like this to instead be MyApp instead of Safari or Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just looked at my browser reports and unless "*aaa*", "*ddd*" and "*this is a test ua*" are actually existing browsers it would seem that GA also tracks unknown user agents.

More seriously, the measurement protocol (on top of which Google Analytics is built) [allows for a user agent override parameter](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#ua) (&ua), which probably would make very little sense if you could only pass in known browser names (after all this is meant so support e.g IoT devices which might not even have a real user agent name).

Comment: Hrm.. indeed it does log arbitrary browser names if that is the only supplied name in the UA. (ie. just MyAppName/1.0). If I append it with all the other stuff it'll pick up on Safari, then Chrome. However not including these other browser names sometimes breaks website compatibility. Oh well.